# Find the positive root of the equation $\cosh x+\cos x-3=0$, other than numerically

Tags: hyperbolic-functions, transcendental-equations, newton-raphson

I know you are able to find the root of the equation by using Newton-Raphson method. But is there any other way?

$$\cosh x+\cos x-3=0$$

I thought maybe you could say that $-1\leq \cos x \leq 1$. 
So saying

$2< \cosh(x) <4$

But then I am unsure what to do next or if you could even do it this way?

Comment: rewrite it in the form $$1/2\,{{\rm e}^{x}}+1/2\,{{\rm e}^{-x}}+1/2\,{{\rm e}^{ix}}+1/2\,{
{\rm e}^{-ix}}-3
=0$$ but a symbolic solution fails

Comment: This equation will be solvable only by using numerical methods. Even the Lambda-W-function does not help.

Comment: can you prove this?

Comment: You also solve the $x=\cosh^{-1}(z))$ case:$\left(\sqrt{z^2-1}+1\right)^i+\left(\sqrt{z^2-1}+z\right)^{-i}+z=3$

Comment: If you wanted to invert the function, then you can find the laplace transform for the inverse function, but it would be a series like $\sum\limits_{n\in\Bbb Z}i^n I_n(1) K_{in}(s)$ using [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function). An integral version the [Jacobi Anger expansion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi–Anger_expansion) does not seem to give a simple integral though, so the Jacobi Anger expansion can be used

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Pade approximation for $cos(x)$ and recall that $cosh(x) = cos(Ix)$:
\begin{equation}
cos(x) \approx \frac{15,120 -6900 x^2+ 313 x^4}{15,120 + 660 x^2 + 13 x^4}
\end{equation}

you can replace in your equation the above and obtain a solvable equation for $x$ (essentially, just using the solutions to a quadratic equation).

Using Pade, one gets $1.8579$ (significant digits), while the true solution reads $1.85792082...$ (so, it seems that Pade will give $5$ digits of accuracy).

Otherwise, maybe some fixed point iteration or Newton secant method would give some converging result too, in a somewhat analytical fashion...

Answer (score 1):

Perform a series expansion around $x=0$

$$f(x)=\cosh (x)+\cos( x)-3=-1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^{4n}}{(4n)!}$$ Let $t=x^4$, truncate to some order and perform series reversion
$$t=z-\frac{z^2}{1680}+\frac{23 z^3}{34927200}-\frac{461
   z^4}{508540032000}+O\left(z^5\right)\quad \text{with}\quad z=12(1+f(x))$$ Since we need $f(x)=0$, then $z=12$ and the above truncated series gives as an *approximation*
$$t=\frac{876658037}{73573500}\implies x=\sqrt[4]{\frac{876658037}{73573500}}=\color{red}{1.8579208}16$$ while the exact solution, as given by Newton method, is $x=\color{red}{1.857920829}$.